# If I have windows on hibernate, and I start ubuntu, will my computer lag?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hibernate

I have my computer set to dual boot, and it runs ubuntu and win 7. I normally don't shut my computer down, because I use it frequently, so I normally put it on hibernate. When I press the power button, the GRUB loader shows up, and then I can choose windows, and resume windows, or I can start loading ubuntu.

If I have windows on hibernate, will it be using up some of my RAM memory, and cause it to lag? Or will I not have a problem at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I have windows on hibernate, will it be using up some of my RAM memory, and cause it to lag? Or will I not have a problem at all?

No your RAM won't be used but you can't access the Windows partitions on Ubuntu if you do so.

Comment: I normally don't access my other partitions (Once in a while I do). If Win 7 is hibernated, then I can't access the Win 7 partition?

Comment: yes you can't.To access your windows 7 partitions,you have to remove hiberfile or shutdown windows fully.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Windows saves its state in a file called hiberfil.sys. If you start (via bootloader) another distribution, that file will not be read and your RAM will be used exclusively for the running OS.
On Linux you will not be able to access the drive where windows is located, since any change of the filesystem would be disjunctive to the state stored in file mentioned above.